# If usertype is jobseeker then redirect to 1st page if usertype is employer then redirect to 2nd page

Tags: php, redirect

Hello i just want to check if the user (who is logging in) has usertype Employer then he should redirect to my-profile.php and if usertype is Jobseeker then he should redirect to latest-jobs.php. Here is my code please help me if you can.

I am trying to add some script in my code but it has some mistake and not working. Now it's redirecting to latest-jobs.php to both (Employer and Jobseeker). Check down my second script.

Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
include("lib/conn.php");

?>
<?php
$email=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if ($email && $password){

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND password= '$password' and status = '1'";
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die ("didn't query");
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );


if ($num == 1){

$_SESSION['ocer']=$email;

header("Location: my-profile.php");

}

else {

header("Location: index.php?l=1");

}

}

?>
```

My second script

```
<?php
session_start();
include("lib/conn.php");

?>
<?php
$email=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


if ($email && $password){

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND password= '$password' and status = '1'";
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die ("didn't query");
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );


if ($num == 1){

$_SESSION['ocer']=$email;

if ($usertype == "Employer") {

header("Location: my-profile.php");

}

else {

header ("Location: latest-jobs.php");

}

}

else {

header("Location: index.php?l=1");

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Did you save your user type in db and if yes,show the table name and column name

Comment: This question does not actually reflect what exact issue you are facing.

Comment: Yes table name is "register" and column name is "usertype"

Comment: are you sure the $num has a 1 or other number?? I think the problem its your query or the result of your query

Comment: You should be using `nysqli_`, not `mysql_`.

Comment: Plain text password storage is a bad idea. 
Not stating what is the problem you are having, instead just "please help"? worse. 
Please look over what it means to ask a good question here, often just by asking the question in the right way will let you answer your own question

Comment: yes $num has a 1 and my login system is working fine i just want to  add some coding to redirect user if he is a employer then redirect to my-profile.php and if he is a jobseeker then redirect to latest-jobs.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution now.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("lib/conn.php");

    $email=$_POST['user'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    if ($email && $password)
    {       
        $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password= '".$password."' and status = '1'";        
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("didn't query". mysql_error());
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($num ==1){
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if($data['usertype'] == 'Employer')
            {
                $_SESSION['ocer'] = $email;
                header("Location: my-profile.php"); 
            }
            else if($data['usertype'] == 'Jobseeker')
            {   
            $_SESSION['ocer'] = $email;
                header("Location: latest-jobs.php");                
            }
        } 
        else{
            header("Location: index.php?l=1");
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: This is very unsafe. Please Google for "SQL Injection".